# verify entrance source in php

Tags: php, referrer

I have a link on the page that opens a contact form in a modal window.

How can I verify that the user clicked on the link to access the contact form, and did not go to the page directly. I don't want users or bots inadvertently browsing to that page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using AJAX would thwart all bots and crawlers.

Comment: @Blender However that page it still be accessible by browsing directly to it not using ajax.

Comment: @dardub: if google has no link to that page, it is not accesible for him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for `$_SERVER['X_HTTP_REQUESTED_WITH']` header, which will be `xmlhttprequest` whenever it's an ajax request

Comment: Hmm.. this option seems viable. Is $_SERVER['X_HTTP_REQUESTED_WITH'] reliable?

Comment: heh that rhymed ... heh hehe heh hehe

Comment: @dardub: yes, robots don't use them

Answer (score 0):

You can use the referral url (you can access this url in PHP using `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`) but you can't rely on it. First because it can be changed using a very simple script and second because that field is not always filled.

Another method is to use session to store the last visited page and then check this in your contact page. Anyway this method will also fail if the user see another page before access to the contact form but the page which you want the users start with was already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Have a form with a hidden field that contains a token, and validate that token with the session on postback.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a variable with it like

```
<a href="contact.php?co=true">Contact Me</a>
```

and in the modal test weather it set or not

```
if(isset($_GET['co'])):
//show the form 
else:
//redirect
endif;
```

or you can use jquery to select that link and sends a variable posted with it like

```
<a href="contact.php" class="contact">Contact Me</a>
$('.contact').click(function(){
 $.post( 'contact.php', { direct: 'no'},function()
{
//call modal from here 
}
);
});
```

then test if direct = no

```
if($_POST['direct'] == 'no'):
//show the form
else:
//redirect
endif;
```

and the jquery solution is more reliable 
Sorry I was wrong

Comment: I'm planning on having post values anyway, but I wasn't sure if that was a reliable method.